# Trying to ping IP of one VM from another VM: Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I have 2 VMs. One acts as a client and the other acts as a server. For the server VM, I set an IP address like this:

```
sudo ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.0.73/24 up
```

And for the client VM, I set the IP address like this:

```
sudo ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.0.77/24 up
```

I was trying to make sure that both the client and the server are in the same subnet on the internal network.

Then I tried to ping the server's IP from the client VM like this:

```
ping 192.168.0.73
```

However, I keep getting the *Destination Host Unreachable* error

Both VMs have 2 nework adapters. The 1st network adapter is a Host-only adapter (same MAC address for both VMs) and the 2nd network adapter is an Internal Network Adapter (same network name and MAC address for both VMs).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check if any firewall is up with `iptables -L`. Also, the MAC addresses should be different for each single virtual NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is the same MAC for both machines. Don't do that. Using the same MAC-ID on different systems on the same network gives all sorts of surprising and unpredictable results.

So, what I guess is happening is something like this:

- ping 192.168.0.73
- What MAC-ID is 192.168.0.73? Do an ARP-request
- Ah! the MAC-ID is my own adapter; so no need to send it on the network
- On my own adapter, I get a ICMP echo request to 192.168.0.73, but I am 192.168.0.77. So I will not answer this request (no pong).

Because Linux (like all OS-s I know) keeps a  cache for ARP, you can see the IP-adderss to MAC-id translation for that machine with

```
arp -a
```

Comment: So both of the machines should have different MAC addresses for both Host-only adapter AND the Internal Network adapter? In other words, in the client VM, the host-only adapter should have MAC address 'a' and the internet network adapter should have MAC address b, and in the server VM, the host-only adapter should have MAC address c and the internal network adapter should have MAC address d (given that a,b,c and d are 4 different addresses)?

Comment: Yes. Always make sure that all mac-id's are unique on your network.

Comment: Hello again. Looks like your solution worked. I'm not getting errors from pinging again. However, I'm now trying to SSH to the client server using Putty (with X11 forwarding). I wrote 192.168.0.77 under Host name and I wrote 24 under port. And then I enabled X11 Forwarding. However, when I open the SSH session, it just shows me a blank screen for 10 seconds before displaying a "Connection Timed Out" error. I even set up an X Server (VcxSrv). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is ssh enabled on your server? Can you from the console of your server ssh to 127.0.0.1?  If not: check that ssh runs (`ps -ef | grep ssh`). If not: start `sshd` from the commandline and see if it works. If ssh works locally, check that there is no filtering done; disable the "firewall" on your virtual machine, if it is active. Make sure that the host does not run any firewall rules.

Comment: For this site: if the solution solves your problem, mark it as solvd; and open a new question for the next problem. In general, don't raise new problems in comments.